# Heavily use of Watin, IE stay open problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, watin

I'm using Watin in C# console app to crawl websites, there are five console app running at the same time. 
The reason I partly use Watin as crawler is because a few websites use javascript(or ajax) to set page content.

Following is the sample code to get a page comment count:

```
        Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
        using (var browser = new IE(commentLink, true))
        {
            browser.Link(Find.ByUrl(commentLink)).WaitUntilExists(20);

            Span commentSpan = browser.Span("COUNT_TOTAL");

            if (commentSpan.Exists)
            {
                int commentCount;
                if (Int32.TryParse(commentSpan.InnerHtml, out commentCount))
                {
                    return commentCount;
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is after running these 5 console app for a while (90 min), a lot of IE instances are stayed open (because of timeout or error or IE is busy), so the system is quite slow and need to reboot.

How do I change my code to prevent this thing happen and make my apps stay effecient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, that in your sample code there is only one moment, when IE will not be close. Since you are inside `using`, even if exception inside of that `using` occurs, browser will be disposed, so everything is fine.

But in the moment of creating browser:

```
new IE(commentLink, true)
```

you are not inside `using`, and there is no magic `try...catch`.
Try this, and let me know if its helped:

```
Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
using (var browser = new IE(true))
{
    browser.GoTo(commentLink);

    browser.Link(Find.ByUrl(commentLink)).WaitUntilExists(20);

    Span commentSpan = browser.Span("COUNT_TOTAL");

    if (commentSpan.Exists)
    {
        int commentCount;
        if (Int32.TryParse(commentSpan.InnerHtml, out commentCount))
        {
            return commentCount;
        }
    }
}
```